# Exclude field from model .NET api

Tags: asp.net, .net

Let's say I have 2 models: Blog and Post. One blog can have multiple Posts and one Post can have only one Blog.

```
public class Blog
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Post> Post { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
    }

    public class Post
    {  
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
        public Blog blog { get; set; }

        public long BlogId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code that allows me to get blogs including a list of posts:

```
 public IEnumerable<Position> GetBlog()
        {
            return _context.Blogs
                          .Include(p => p.Posts)
                          .ToList();
        }
```

The issue is that the return is correct but the post object includes the blog object as well. I don't want that. This is an example of returned Blog list JSON. As you can see, the blog has a list of Posts BUT the post includes the blog object as well!

```
[
 {name: "1", [posts: {id: 1, blog: {name: "1", posts: []}]}},
 {name: "2", [posts: {id: 2, blog: {name: "2", posts: []}]}}
]
```

Comment: Make a class without the blog and return that. Or set it to NULL

Comment: Yeah, I can do that but it cannot prevent the database/system from querying extra field. I want a way to tell the system that I don't need the blog object inside the posts, please don't make any query or population